# How to get granted and expires fields of commerce license updated?

Tags: commerce

I have similar problem as described on [Commerce License Billing: How do I charge or refund a prorated amount when the user's plan changes and the billing cycle is prepaid?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/191700) by @wizonesolutions, but with different goal.

On a Drupal 7 website with the Commerce License Billing module used for subscriptions, the changing subscriptions plan by saving the new product_id on the license entity ($license->product_id) does in fact update the license and the due amount on the next recurring payment order, however, it does not update the `granted` and `expires` fields of the license.

So I tried to get those fields' values from the license, make my calculations and save them together with the whole license entity like so:

```
$bct=$form_state['storage']['target_product']->cl_billing_cycle_type[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'];
    if ($bct == '1') { // hourly
      $target_date = strtotime('+1 hour', REQUEST_TIME);
      $license[arg(1)]->expires = $target_date;
    } elseif ($bct == '2') { // daily
      $target_date = strtotime('+1 day', REQUEST_TIME);
      $license[arg(1)]->expires = $target_date;
    } elseif ($bct == '3') { // monthly
      $target_date = strtotime('+1 month', REQUEST_TIME);
      $license[arg(1)]->expires = $target_date;
    } elseif ($bct == '4') { // quarterly
      $target_date = strtotime('+3 months', REQUEST_TIME);
      $license[arg(1)]->expires = $target_date;
    } elseif ($bct == '5') { // biannually
      $target_date = strtotime('+6 months', REQUEST_TIME);
      $license[arg(1)]->expires = $target_date;
    } else { // biannually
      $target_date = strtotime('+1 year', REQUEST_TIME);
      $license[arg(1)]->expires = $target_date;
    }
    $license[arg(1)]->granted = strtotime("now");
    $license[arg(1)]->product_id = $form_state['storage']['selected_plan'];
    entity_save('commerce_license', $license[arg(1)]);
    drupal_set_message('License has been updated.');
```

And the `admin/commerce/licenses` page after saving the license entity shows that all the relevant fields - new product_id, granted and expired fields have been in fact updated.

But the problem is that when expire time comes, the `granted` field reverts back to initial value and the `expired` field's value is calculated based on the initial `granted` field.

In other words, guess I have two billing cycles - hourly and daily - and if an initial order is placed with hourly billing cycle, then license with the following fields is created:

```
Cycle: Hourly   
Granted: 15 January 2018 - 17:50    
Expires: 15 January 2018 - 18:50
```

If I update the license with the new product id, granted and expires field then the `admin/commerce/licenses` shows:

```
Cycle: Daily    
Granted: 15 January 2018 - 17:52    
Expires: 16 January 2018 - 17:52
```

And when 16 January 2018 - 17:52 comes and all the relevant cron tasks are processed then the same page shows:

```
Cycle: Daily    
Granted: 15 January 2018 - 17:52    
Expires: 15 January 2018 - 20:48
```

Meanwhile bunch of extra orders are charged and the new recurring order with `Recurring: Open` status are created and then only the license admin page showing the granted and expires fields (with values behind from 16 January 2018 - 17:52) constantly changing with every cron execution:

```
Cycle: Daily    
Granted: Active 15 January 2018 - 17:52 
Expires: 16 January 2018 - 01:48
```

So my question is:

If changing the values for the `granted` and `expires` fields in license entity does not take effect, where else I should be looking for changing those values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After monitoring how database tables change with recurring products, I've noticed that saving license with the new data was not sufficient and that the `cl_billing_cycle` should also be updated with the new granted and expire dates.

I am doing that with a direct database query for now. Let me know if there is a better way to update the `cl_billing_cycle`.